# Change title of pivot chart

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

How do I get the title of my pivot chart to change and show up. Pseudocode below:

```
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim PChart As ChartObject

lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 3

'Set data range
Set PRange = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow - 3, 11)

Set PCache = wb2.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Cells(lastRow, 6), _
    TableName:="VarietyByTerritoryTable")
```

This is working as intended. The `lastRow` variable is finicky but gets the job done. This is all in a `With` block. I have some code after this that adds fields to the PTable but is working so I am choosing to omit.

Now I create the chart. Creating the chart works, I just can't get the title to show up.

```
Set PChart = wb2.Sheets(1).ChartObjects.Add(300, 200, 550, 200)
With PChart
    .Chart.SetSourceData PTable.TableRange2
    .Chart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked
    .Name = "Territory"
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = strVar & " in " & strTerr
End With
```

Error shows up in the `.SetElement()` line.

Additional questions:

a) what do the numbers in the `.ChartObjects.Add(##, ##, ###, ##)` do? They change the location I assume. Do the last two deal with the size of the chart?

b) Can I make the title of the chart be the name from TableName in the `Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=.Cells(lastRow, 6), _
    TableName:="VarietyByTerritoryTable")` bit? If so, can I have spaces in the TableName part? (i.e. change to `TableName := "Variety By Territory"`)

c) same question but with the `PChart.Name`. Can I make the title off of this, and if so, should I avoid spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing the `.Chart` in your `SetElement` line. So try this:

   ```
   .Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
   .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = strVar & " in " & strTerr
   ```
2. For [`ChartObjects Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobjects.add) you are correct, the last 2 value refers to the width and height.
3. You can certainly make the name of the chart same with the table name and yes, spaces are allowed in pivot table names.
4. Same for chart titles, spaces are ok.